# Reading part of json into c# object

Tags: c#, json

I have pretty big json string and I am trying to read into object in azure functions only small part of it and I am not sure how to do it.

Link to sample json https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#workitem.updated

I tried to create class but I dont really know how to access "WorkItemType" from json because it looks nested into "Fields".

My code of object

```
public class jsonObject
    public string System.WorkItemType  { get; set; }
    public string System.State  { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing here

```
dynamic eventData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<jsonObject>();
```

Comment: try using : http://json2csharp.com/ or similar for the structure of json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class jsonObject
    public string WorkItemType  { get; set; }
    public string State  { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
jsonObject eventData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<jsonObject>();
```

eventData object contains your data